# OData Service for SQL Azure read only?

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, azure, wcf-data-services, azure-sql-database

according to here: http://watwp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Architecture%20Diagrams

> The SQL Azure OData Service is a sample WCF Data Service built on top
>   of a SQL Azure (or SQL Server) database using Entity Framework 4.1
>   Code First.
>
> **The current version of this service only supports Read operations** and,
>   in addition to exposing the SQL Azure database as an OData feed, it
>   adds a security layer to manage authentication / authorization.

so does it mean the my windows phone app will only be able to read from sql azure and not write to ? or can i do it by creating a data service on the asp.net server ?
i'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this is saying is that the **sample** OData service that they provided only implements *read* operations.  If you want read *and* write, you're going to have to roll that yourself.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you mean by the sample OData service they provided ? i have created a new project from their template `windows phone cloud application` here:http://code.google.com/p/dobberman/source/browse/#svn%2Fdobberman%2Ftrunk%2FWPCloudApp26 can you please tell me where that service is ? thanks.